# onclick ofr radio button jquery

Tags: jquery

I have jsp file with both html and js function included in that. Now I am trying to avoid writing js inside the jsp. So I created a separate js file and I am moving the scripts from jsp to the js file. Everything works fine except for the below code.

Existing code

```
<input class="required" type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_yes"  onclick="showDetails();"/>

 <%if(isOwner.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){%>
  <script>
   var a = document.getElementById("radio_yes");
   var evnt = a["onclick"];
   if (typeof(evnt) == "function") {
       evnt.call(a);
   }
 </script>
<%}

<script>
   function showDetails(){//Code 
  }
</script>
```

This above code is present in the jsp. I tried to move the js function showDetails() into a separate js file like below. Also removed the onClick function in the html.
After moving

```
<input class="required" type="radio" name="radio" id="radio_yes"/>
```

JS file(test.js)

```
$(function() {
   $('#radio_yes').click(showDetails);

    function showDetails(){//Code
   }
});
```

But when I separated like this, I am not sure how to write the below script for radio button inside the js file. This is an existing code and I am not sure why we have to write the onclick for a radio button like this.

```
<script>
   var a = document.getElementById("radio_yes");
   var evnt = a["onclick"];
   if (typeof(evnt) == "function") {
       evnt.call(a);
   }
</script>
```

The functionality is, when the user clicks radio, some text fields are displayed which are currently hidden. The user fills in the details and moves to the next page. When the user comes back to this page again, if the radio button is clicked, it should display all the text fields with the data the user entered. Now my issue is, the radio button is showed as checked, but the below text fields are not displayed when I come back to this page.
Seems like the click is nt triggered when the user comes back. Because once I come back the text fields are not displayed. If I click on the yes radio button once again, the fields are displayed.

Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: I think you need to use `trigger` like `$('#radio_yes').trigger('click')`

Comment: @Satpal..Thanks for the reply. So I should remove the avove code from jsp and write inside the js file as $('#radio_yes').trigger('click')

Comment: Yes, You need to do so

Comment: may be you should move your `click` event in the `doc ready`

Comment: @Satpal..I tried the trigger method..But that is not working..

Answer (score 0):

What you can do for this:

see if you redirected to other page and when you come back to this page again and if your `radio` is checked then you have to do some `if(){}` check and see if that elem is checked fire the `click` event.

```
$(function(){ //<---------this is document ready
   if($('#radio_yes:checked').length > 0){
       $('#radio_yes').click(showDetails).click(); //<----trigger it on load
   }
   $('#radio_yes').click(showDetails);
});

function showDetails(){// <--move this in global scope
}
```

Updates:

```
<%if(isOwner.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){%>
 <script>
   $(function(){ //<---------this is document ready
     if($('#radio_yes:checked').length > 0){
        $('#radio_yes').click(showDetails).click(); //<----trigger it on load
     }
     $('#radio_yes').click(showDetails);
   });
 </script>
<%}%>
```

and you **can move your showDetails function in a separate js file and add before above script.**

Comment: @Jai..thanks for ur reply. what does this do? $('#radio_yes').click(showDetails).click(); Also I cannot do this on load of the page coz this radio button will not be checked always. Only if this is checked, it should display the below fields..I have update dmy question..Can u please check that

Comment: Ok..I have updated the qn..Let me know if u need any clarification on this...It checks for one condition and if its true, then have to execute the click event on the radio..

Comment: @user1049057 see the updates may be this could help.

Comment: @Jai..I need to check for this condition in jsp <%if(isOwner.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){%> and execute the script..How is that possible?

Comment: @Jai..Yea we have to do using if() condition only. That we are using in the jsp like <%if(isOwner.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){%> <script>...</script> So is it possible to check the condition in the jsp and then call teh function in the js file>